# Adding PHP logic withing .twig file

Tags: php, twig

I am not very familiar with TWIG templates and I need to add a bit of logic to a template file based on the URL. I know how to do it in PHP, but am sort of lost here.

I can get the full URL using {{ app.request.uri }} but what I am really trying to do is something like this:

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ($uri == "/page1" ||strpos($uri, "/page1/")  !== false) {
       echo " id="item1";
}
```

Is something like this possible? Thanks

Comment: are you also using Symfony framework or just Twig?

Answer (score 4):

you could try it with the [in](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator) Operator, but routing logic should be outside of the template file

you should do this logic in your Controller and set a variable "true".

#### controller.php

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$item = null;
if ($uri == "/page1" ||strpos($uri, "/page1/")  !== false) {
       $item = "id=item1";
}
$this->render('MyBundle:mytwig.html.twig',array("item"=>$item));
```

#### mytwig.html.twig

```
{% if item %}
  {{ item }} is only written if item is set
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of logic does *not* belong in templates. Leave that code outside of your template and assign the result to a variable (instead of directly echoing it). Pass that variable to the Twig template. Output the variable.

Templates are exclusively for presentation, not for containing complicated logic code.

Comment: OK, how would such logic look like in controller? Seems like a pretty steep learning curve at a first glance, for someone not familiar with it...

Comment: Basically exactly what you have right now. Just instead of `echo`, you do `$id = ...`. Then pass `$id` to Twig. Then in Twig you do `{{ id }}`. Done. The basic idea is trivial: all "decision making" code is *outside* the template, that code produces **no output** (no `echo`, no nothing). All *output* is *inside* the template. It just keeps both sides very simple and easy to maintain.